# Angular Build-Config: add conditional file (robots.txt)

Tags: angular

I have two build configurations "production" and "development". By selecting one of the following two commands I can decide for which config I want to build the app:

1. `ng build --configuration=development`
2. `ng build --configuration=production`

And in the `angular.json` I specify the build options for each config:

```
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
           .
           .
           .
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              .
              .
              .
            },
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              .
              .
              .
            }
          }
        },
```

Basically I change the `environment.ts` as well as the `index.html` according to the selected build config.

Is there a way to have two robots.txt files in the project folder, for instance `robots.dev.txt` and `robots.prod.txt` and conditionally add one of them as `robots.txt` to the dist folder during the build? Pretty much how I do it with the index file.
The purpose is to prevent all search engine robots from indexing my development build, but allow them to index the production build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that this can be handled from the `angular.json`.

As an alternative, the `robots.txt` can be copied as a post-build step. To do this,
install `copy` npm package to have a copy CLI command, which is cross-platform:

```
npm install copy --save-dev
```

Add to the `package.json` a script for the production build with following commands:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod && copy robots.txt dist"
```

Run `npm run build:prod` to have a production build with `robots.txt` in it.

The above example assumes, that the `robots.txt` is in the same directory as the `package.json` and it assumes, that the built app is in the root of the `dist` folder.

## Update

If the copied file needs to be renamed the [copy-file-from-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-files-from-to) package could be used. It is especially handy if there are more files from different sources and they also need to be renamed. To use it in the context of the question do the following steps:

Install the thirdpaty as development dependency:

```
npm install copy-files-from-to --save-dev
```

Create a configuration file for `copy-files-from-to` named as `copyFiles.json` in the root of the project with following content:

```
{
    "copyFiles": [
        {
            "from": "robots.dev.txt",
            "to": "dist/robots.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Create an npm script, that uses `copy-files-from-to` with the above config:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod && copy-files-from-to --config copyFiles.json"
```

Run `npm run build:prod` and the `robots.dev.txt` content will be copied after the build in `dist/robots.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. Is there also an option to rename the file during copying? For instance `copy robots.dev.txt dist robots.txt`?

Comment: I checked the `copy` thirdparty and did not found any option for the renaming. So I updated the answer with another solution, that makes the renaming of the file possible.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I did it.

In my `angular.json` file, I defined assets to be included in the `architect->build->options`:

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/robots.txt",
          "src/sitemap.txt"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment on the previous answers because I have a new account. I just wanted to add two things. Firstly:

- Use the `copy` option if you want a file to have different content in different environments.
- Use the `angular.json` option if you just want to include/exclude certain files in different environments.

Secondly, I would like to expand a bit on the `angular.json` option by adding a more complete example:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "default/assets/for/all/builds"
    ],
    .
    .
    .
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "assets": [
        "assets/for/production/build"
      ],
      .
      .
      .
    },
    "development": {
      "assets": [
        "assets/for/development/build"
      ],
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
}
```

When specifying assets for a build (e.g. "production" and "development" in the example above) the default assets (under "options") will not be applied.